# To store Employee details with below requirement which collection_type can be used?

Tags: java, collections

I want to store `Employee_id (int)`, `Employee_name (String)` & `Employee_Salary(long)` in a collection. Out of which `Employee_id` should always be unique & sorted in ascending order. `Employee_names` can be duplicated.
Please suggest me which Java-Collection I can use & how will be the basic program for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a `TreeMap<Integer,Employee>` where the key is the employee ID.

Comment: So Employee object will contain Employee_name & Employee_salary, is it??

Comment: Yes, I would also include employee ID in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [**TreeMap**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) here is an example:

**JAVA**

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

...

 /* This is how to declare TreeMap */
  TreeMap<Integer, String> tmap = 
         new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

  /*Adding elements to TreeMap*/
  tmap.put(1, "Data1");
  tmap.put(23, "Data2");
  tmap.put(70, "Data3");
  tmap.put(4, "Data4");
  tmap.put(2, "Data5");

  /* Display content using Iterator*/
  Set set = tmap.entrySet();
  Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
     System.out.print("key is: "+ mentry.getKey() + " & Value is: ");
     System.out.println(mentry.getValue());
  }
```

You can also use [**HashMap**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (No sorting applied)

Comment: **sorted** is not apply to `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use HashMap for storing non duplicates Employee_id.
You'll need two HashMap to store the following: 
Employee_id, Employee_Name, Employee_Salary

```
//this will hold the id and name
HashMap<Integer, String> employeeHM = new HashMap<>();
//this will hold the id of employeeHM's HashMap and the salary
HashMap<Integer, Long> salaryHM = new HashMap<>();
```

Like @ThatAwesomeCoder said, HashMap lacks the sorting. You could overcome this by making a loop that read all the id from the employeeHM and use a sort function to sort it to an ArrayList Collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store the employee data as key-value pairs, you can use TreeMap with EmployeeID as unique key. If you need to store it in form of a set, how about using Treeset's overridden constructor which accepts a Comparator? Inside the comparator, you can specify the comparison logic. Just my two cents..